# docker-compose gives error "cant access the file because it is being used by another process". Not same with docker vanilla

Tags: docker-compose

Im running my docker container with

> Docker run  kalle:anka -p 8888:80 -p 5045:5045 -p 5672:5672

without any problem. But when I try to achieve the same thing with docker-compose I get the error

> ERROR: for myapp.api_1  Cannot start service myapp.api: failed to
>   create endpoint myapp.api_1 on network nat: hnsCall failed in Win32:
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process. (0x20)

The error above seems to have something to do with the port mapping. (When I remove those I get passed that problem.)

... I'll keep this question short, please ask if yo miss any details

Relevant part of my docker-compose.yaml

```
> version: '3.4'
> 
> services:   myapp.api:
>     image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myappapi
>     ports: 
>     - "8888:80"  
>     - "5045:5045"
>     - "5672:5672"
```